# Function holomorphic on some region but nonholomorphic in another region.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I am self studying complex analysis and I have a question about holomorphic functions:
Are singularities the only thing that makes a function nonholomorphic ? in other words, is there a complex function that is defined for example in the whole complex plane (i.e. no singularities ) which is holomorphic on some region but nonholomorphic in another region.

I think such function does not exist because the values of a holomorphic function in different places of the complex plane are linked by the Cauchy integral formula, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: A disappointing answer: you can define a functions _piecewise_ so that in one region it is obviously holomorphic, but in another it is something random, like $\Re(z)$.

Comment: Being defined in the whole complex plane is not the same as having no singularities. For example, define $f(z)= 1/z, z\ne 0,$ $f(0)=0.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks, I think a found the example given by Stella interesting since it is even continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)=\overline{z}$ doesn't have any singularities and is not holomorphic.

We can achieve the function being holomorphic on a region with a piece-wise definition. Let $f(z)=z$ on the unit disc and $f(z)=\overline{z}^{-1}$ everywhere else. Not only does this satisfy your desire, it's also continuous, since $\overline{z}=z^{-1}$ holds on the unit circle.

Comment: Is it holomorphic on some region of the complex plane ?

Comment: @user431768 No.

Comment: No, because at no point $z=x+iy$ does the function $f(z) = \overline{z} = x-iy$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: @DavidBowman I am looking for a function which is holomorphic on some region but nonholomorphic in another region.

Comment: @user431768 Let $f(z)=z$ on the unit disc and $f(z)=\overline{z}^{-1}$ everywhere else. Not only does this satisfy your criterion, it's also continuous!

Comment: @user431768 I gave one in a comment on your question.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I like the continuous example you gave, maybe it is better to add it in the answer.

Comment: @user431768 Done